# read port RB7 or other port from PICF184550 in program language C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, microcontroller, pic, led

I'm using the picdem F184550, I want to read the value of the led, I'm using the mplab ide v8.63 with a C compiler. but I don't have a idea how to interface with the port RB7 where my led with a resistor is connected to. The question is, how can I read the port RB7 where my led is connected to in the program language C. thanks! (see picture[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the compiling suite you are using.

Those provided by Microchip (C18 for 18F MCUs) usually define all available ports & registers in a header file specific to your device (something like p18F4550.h in your case).

In this header, you will have a structure definition corresponding to your specific port register.
You can access to your specific RB7 I/O,within the following field : PORTBbits.RB7

Comment: thanks for your comment! I will try it. it's the C18 compiler for Microchip.

Comment: Do you have any idea wich value I can retrieve? Of must I write the value of PORTBbits.RB7 to putty to see these values?

Comment: Reading the RB7, you will only have a one bit value (0 or 1) stating if your output pin is driven to low or high state. I guess it's configured as output as it's driving a led. So basically it will reflect the direct state of your LED lightning status.